# How to get attribute value with correct datatype from Row in java spark sql

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-java

I am using Spark Java (not scala or python).

I have a dataframe `(Dataset<Row>)` and I want to access specific fields from the Row. I have been able to get the field value if it is a String, but I don't know what to do if it is a Long, Int...etc. Here is how I access it if its a String attribute:

```
final String id = row.getAs("id").toString();
```

Can the `getAs()` Row method be used for other datatypes as well? I don't know if it can properly type the retrieved value. If in the database I queried, quantity is type Long then I want to retrieve it from Row as type Long too. Such as:

```
final Long quantity = row.getAs("quantity");
```

I saw that there are Row methods like `getLong()`, `getInt()` but I don't know how to use them because the methods take in an int. I only have the field name of the value I want to access so I can only pass in a field name string.

Answer (score 1):

getAs(column) method already gives you the type of the column's value, then you can just cast it if you know it in order to handle it.

```
Long myId = (Long)row.getAs("id")
```

Other methods rely on the index of the value, so if you have a dataset having those columns:

> longId | stringValue

then you could use:

```
row.getLong(0)
row.getString(1)
```

see more: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Row.html#getAs(java.lang.String)